# How to add a string that contains whitespace to a Tkinter Treeview column

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I use the tree.insert method to insert data into the treeview widget. Under the values option I specify the string variable where to get the data. If the string contains whitespace then the string gets broken up into smaller strings which are placed into a list. How can I add data into the treeview columns without getting it truncated to the first whitespace?

Thank you.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
app = tk.Tk()
tree = ttk.Treeview(app)
tree.grid(row=0, column=0)
tree.config(columns=('Value1'), selectmode='browse')
tree.column('#0', width=150, minwidth=10, stretch=tk.YES)
tree.column('Value1', width=80, minwidth=10, stretch=tk.YES)
tree.heading('#0', text='Name', anchor=tk.W)
tree.heading('Value1', text='Value', anchor=tk.W)
data = [['John', '123456'], ['Mary', '123 456'], ['Edward', 'abcdef'], ['Lisa', 'ab cd ef']]
for item in data:
    print(item[1], type(item[1]))
    tree.insert("", 'end', item[0], text=item[0], values=item[1])
    print(tree.item(item[0])['values'], type(tree.item(item[0])['values']))
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`values` expects an iterable, so when you pass a `string` to it, it will tend to do weird things. Easiest way to fix it in your code is to pass it as a tuple:

```
tree.insert("", 'end', item[0], text=item[0], values=(item[1],))
```

Answer (score 2):

Its not a big task just give a backslash before a white-space, like :-

```py
data = [['John', '123456'], ['Mary', '123\ 456'], ['Edward', 'abcdef'], ['Lisa', 'ab\ cd\ ef']]
```

It will show you the white-spaces in your GUI because '123\ 456' will treated as a single element in type 'list'.

Comment: my fortune. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Of the two answers given here, I tend to disagree with setting
`values=item[1]` to `values=(item[1])` since I still had an issue with Treeview splitting around spaces.

I tried the escaping solution and that worked perfectly. I'd take it a little further if I may and change your `values=(item[1])` to `values=(item[1].replace(" ", "\ "))` so your line would read::

```
tree.insert("", 'end', item[0], text=item[0], values=(item[1].replace(" ", "\ "))
```

...just as a catch all